# What is the meaning of the '@' operator in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, symbols

I have this code:

```
  mix xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys)
  | x<=y = x : mix xs yys
  | otherwise = y : mix xxs ys
```

But I don't know what the `@` means.

Comment: I get "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)" with your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not an operator; it's part of the pattern syntax. In the case of `yys@(y:ys)`, if the second argument successfully matches against `(y:ys)`, the entire value matched is bound to `yys` as well.

So, if you called `min [1,2] [3,4]`, then `y` would be bound to `3`, `ys` to `[4]`, and `yys` to `[3,4]`.

Answer (score 4):

This is an [*as-pattern* [Haskell tutorial]](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) it is used to have a reference both to the entire list `xxs`, the head of the list `x` and the tail of the list `xs` (and of course the same for the second list).

The pattern will only fire if all the subpatterns match as well, so in this case if *both* the two lista re non-empty. It is often used as an optimization, since now you can use the first or second parameter `xxs` or `yys` in the body of the function.